# How do I change the tempbuild folder for msbuild?

Tags: configuration, tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I have a build server running msbuild.

When a build is kicked off, the build server gets the source files and drops them into a folder called c:\tempbuilds\

Then it performs the build and drops the build into the output folder.

How can I change the location of the ***c:\tempbuilds*** folder on the build server?

Answer (score 1):

In your server definition in 2008 (Build -> Manage Build Agents) edit the build agent.

In the dialog that pops up then, change the working folder to wherever you like.

You can use the placeholder `$(BuildDefinitionPath)` to create a folder based on the name of the build definition itself to make sure each build has its own folder.